# For any function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$, $\{x : f(x) < \alpha \}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\sum)$ be a measurable space and let $D \subseteq X$

Let $\sum_D$ be the subspace $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of D.

Then for any function $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$, we have 4 equivalent statements.

(i) $\{x : f(x) < \alpha \} \in \sum_D$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

(ii) $\{x : f(x) \leq \alpha \} \in \sum_D$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

(iii) $\{x : f(x) > \alpha \} \in \sum_D$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

(iv) $\{x : f(x) \geq \alpha \} \in \sum_D$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Why are these statements significant and why are they true?
What is the intuition?

Looking at the first bit of proof, we assume (i) is true. 
Then

$\{x : f(x) \leq \alpha \} = \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x : f(x) < \alpha + 2^{-n} \} \in \sum_D$

Where does $2^{-n}$ come from?

Comment: Remember Zeno's paradox of [Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise)? It is the same here: to get "less than or equal" you take _all possible_ "less than". That's why you have $2^{-n}$. Could be any other positive and shrinking to zero sequence.

Comment: Ok, But why do we need those 4 statements? I mean why are they significant? If f(x) < $\alpha$ then so what?  Does $x \in X$?

Comment: $x\in D$ as $f$ is defined on $D$ only. The statements are equivalent to $f$ being [Lebesgue measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function).

Comment: Ok, why is $\alpha$ so significant?

Comment: Lastly why is their an intersection in the second to last line in the question rather than a union?

Comment: Measurability of a function is equivalent to _all_ its sublevel (superlevel) sets being measurable. The word **all** makes it important for $\alpha$ to be arbitrary. Look at the link above.

Comment: I understand now thanks